# Vanity A/B testing with page caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, vanity

I'm using [Vanity](http://vanity.labnotes.org/) to do my A/B testing but I also have page caching for the pages the experiment is running on.  Because of that, the user will actually see both options as they navigate around the site.  I would be fine with that however I know that Vanity keeps track of which option a single user is seeing and attempts to show that same option throughout the site.

So what I'm wondering is, let's say a user comes to my site and views Option A.  Vanity (I think) records them as an "Option A" participant.  Now that user goes to a different cached page, and because of the caching they see Option B and "converts".

Is vanity going to record that user as an "Option A" conversion or an "Option B" conversion?

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with the creator of Vanity and it is indeed important to turn off caching of pages you're trying to A/B test with in order to get accurate results.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently started helping to maintain Vanity.

This question is similar to the issue reported [here](https://github.com/assaf/vanity/issues/47), which was recently addressed and closed by [PR#144](https://github.com/assaf/vanity/pull/144) (just merged onto master, will be included in the next release).

A cache string for a user can be generated using (from a controller):

```
Vanity.playground.participant_info(vanity_identity)
```